# Display MySql Data Using Div

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

How to display images from mysql database, specifically two images in a row. I've read many articles in stack overflow, all of them discussed using the table tag. But I couldn't find any article using div.
Here is my SQL code which is not completely correct.(displays images, but not in correct order) :

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE tag='$tag' ");
while($info=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if($count==2) //two images per row
        {
           print "</div>";
           $count = 0;
        }
        if($count==0)
        print '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 gallery-display">';
        ?>
    <figure>
            <a href="first-image.php">
                <img src="1.jpg" alt="Texture Paper" class="display-image">
            </a>
            <a href="first-image.php" class="figcaption">
                <h3>Texture Paper</h3>
            </a>
        </figure>

            <?php
        $count++;
        print '</div>';
    }
    if($count>0)
       print "";
    ?>
```

This How Code should come !

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 gallery-display">
        <figure>
            <a href="first-image.php">
                <img src="1.jpg" alt="Texture Paper" class="display-image">
            </a>
            <a href="first-image.php" class="figcaption">
                <h3>Texture Paper</h3>
            </a>
        </figure>
        <!--figure-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 gallery-display">
        <figure>
            <a href="sec-image.php">
                <img src="2..jpg" alt="Photo (:" class="display-image">
            </a>
            <a href="sec-image.php" class="figcaption">
                <h3>Photo Caption</h3>
            </a>
        </figure>

    </div>
    <!--.gallery-display-->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 gallery-display">
..........loop code continues.......
```

Comment: Be very careful to use [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). `mysql_query` is tricky to get right and should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and is a safer way to compose queries.

Comment: Use any CSS framework just as [tag:zurb-foundation]

Comment: Can any suggest replacing code to show two images in a row ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php%20/). You might want to check around before posting this kind of stuff, because this appears to be a duplicate/very similar to

[PHP: display entries from Database in groups of five?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801997/php-display-entries-from-database-in-groups-of-five)