# php list and group data

Tags: php, html

I want to group the data as 3 or 2 in the foreach loop while listing the data with PHP. Is it possible to do this?

There are 30 tables in total.
I want to group by 3 by 3 and I want to give "first" class to the first data per group.

Like the picture I want to list.
[image]
Sample:

```
<div class="container">
    <?php foreach ($query as $row): ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="post-1 first"></div>
            <div class="post-2"></div>
            <div class="post-3"></div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: display entries from Database in groups of five?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801997/php-display-entries-from-database-in-groups-of-five)

Comment: This is not what I said.

Comment: @MesutBla I'm not clear what you are asking. Perhaps you could add a diagram that shows what your raw data looks like and how it will be mapped to the rows and columns.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The answer is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you pass the data you want to group into `array_chunk()` and determine the limit, and then we say `$key==0` in the first element of each group.

```
<div class="container">
    <?php foreach (array_chunk($query, 3) as $chunk): ?>
        <div class="row">
            <?php foreach ($chunk as $key => $row): ?>
                <div class="post <?php if ($key == 0): ?>first<?php endif; ?>"></div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```